# .javaFXApplet (Unknown Source) ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, embedded-resource, fxml

please help me , when I run my program in the browser it return this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at e1.E1.start(E1.java:30)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown....
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("u.png").toExternalForm());
```

This is the complete code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class E1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField UserF = new TextField();
        UserF.setPromptText("nom d'utilisateur");
        UserF.setLayoutX(50);
        Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("u.png").toExternalForm()); // error occurs here
       ImageView pic = new ImageView(img);
        pic.setLayoutX(-100);
        pic.setLayoutY(-60);
        PasswordField  PassF = new PasswordField ();
        PassF.setPromptText(" mot de passe");
        PassF.setLayoutX(50);
        PassF.setLayoutY(50);

        Button login = new Button("Login");
        login.setLayoutX(100);
        login.setLayoutY(100);
       // btn.setMaxSize(100, 200);

       BorderPane Menu= new BorderPane(); 
       Group root = new Group();

       root.getChildren().addAll(UserF,PassF,login,pic);
       Menu.setCenter(root);
       Menu.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 25% 25% to 100% 100%,  #6db3f2 , #1e69de)");

        Scene scene;
        scene= new Scene(Menu);


    //    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: but it work in Standalone mode . Help !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Examples cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Comment: Did you modify the source code after you got the exception? Line 30 does not make sense to me...

Comment: the probleme that it can't find the URL of the picture ,here : Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("u.png").toExternalForm());

Answer (score 0):

Works now , it solved by :

replacing

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("u.png").toExternalForm());
```

by :

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icons/u.png"));
```

Comment: Do not post additional information as answer, if it doesn't **answer** the question. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34380067/edit) instead.